# how to shuffle a deck of cards using a basic switch method in java

Tags: java, shuffle

I am creating the basis for a card game right now, I am doing just some basic functions for cards. I want to shuffle the cards, but don't know how to write the function for it. It will be called in the main program here is the deck class I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*  ;      //capture mouse events
    import java.awt.Graphics ;
    import java.awt.Event;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Deck 
    {
        private  Random random = new Random (); 
        protected Card cards[] = new Card[52] ; 

        protected int numcards = 0; 

        public Deck()
        {
            int i = 0; 
            for (int s = 1; s<5 ; s++)
            {
                for (int n=1; n<14 ; n++)
                {
                    cards[i] = new Card(n,s);
                    i++; 
                    numcards =  numcards + 1; 
                }
            }

        }

        public void giveCard(Deck p) 
        {
             numcards =  numcards - 1; 
             p.takeCard(cards[numcards]); 
             return;  
        }

        public void takeCard(Card c)
        {
            cards[numcards] = c;
            numcards = numcards + 1;

        }

        public void shuffle ()
        {
             int temp;  
             for (int i = 0; i<52; i++)
             {
                 //cards[i] = temp ; 
             }
        }

        public void draw (Container c ,Graphics g, int x , int y  )
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<numcards; i++)
            {
                 cards[i].draw(c, g, x+i*20,y) ; 
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: My suggestion: google "simple shuffle algorithms java"

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `Card[]` into `List<Card>` instead, you can simply use `Collections.shuffle(cards)`. Otherwise, loop through the array, at each point, swap the current card with a randomly selected card.

Comment: what would that look like because right now i have cards[i] = temp. i want the next time to randomly pick another card and sore in the temp variable like this   cards[i] = temp temp = (randomlypickedcard), (randomlypickedcard) = cards[i] like im trying to use the basic switch algorithm but i dont know how to say pick a random card from the deck

Comment: `int j = Random.nextInt(52); Card temp = cards[i]; cards[i] = cards[j]; cards[j] = temp;`

Comment: it wont work because it says non static method nextInt cannot be refferd from static context

Comment: typo.... `int j = random.nextInt(52);` Though you should have been able to get that one.

Comment: The algorithm stated will not cause all card orders to occur with equal probability. If you insist on reinventing the wheel, do a proper Fisher-Yates shuffle instead.

Comment: Assuming `Random` is actually uniform, how does this favor some shuffles over others? ; Just looked it up, that is a Fisher-Yates shuffle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is have a card array as the deck, randomly select two indices, and swap the values. You will need a third "dummy" variable to hold one of the card values during the swap. You can have a loop do this some random large number of times (500-1000) for a nice "realistic" shuffle.

Fun fact: this is actually the type of algorithm official computerized blackjack and poker websites use for their shuffling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use to shuffling the top half of the deck into the bottom half of the deck, which simulates a bridge/riffle shuffle.  This saves on performance since you don't have to really iterate through the entire deck for a shuffle.

```
Random r = new Random();
int halfMark = cards.length / 2;
// Iterate through the top half of the deck
for (int i = 0; i < halfMark; i++) {
    // Generate a random index in the bottom half
    int shuffleIndex = r.nextInt(halfMark) + halfMark;

    // Swap the cards
    int temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[shuffleIndex];
    cards[shuffleIndex] = temp;
}
```

If you're wanting to do more than one shuffle, just wrap the for loop in another for loop controlling how many times you want to shuffle the top half of the deck into the bottom half.